# iterate through multiple tuples and return string

Tags: python, string, function, tuples

I'm trying iterate through multiple tuples in a list and return the items in each tuple in a particular order into a string.

For example, if I input:

```
['ABCD', 'EFGH', 'IJKL']
```

I would expect it to return:

```
'AEIBFJCGKDHL'
```

Thank you in advance for you help!

Comment: I see no tuples here...

Answer (score 4):

You need [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
lst = ['ABCD', 'EFGH', 'IJKL']

''.join(l for t in zip(*lst) for l in t)
# 'AEIBFJCGKDHL'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import itertools
''.join(itertools.chain(*zip(*mylist)))
```

Or:

```
import itertools
''.join(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(*mylist)))
```

(Thanks to juanpa.arrivillaga and PM_2Ring for helpful comments.)

Comment: maybe `chain.from_iterable`

Comment: While it's certainly preferable to pass `.join` a list than an iterator when you have a choice  (because it has to scan the strings twice), when you don't have a choice there's no need to call `list` explicitly - `.join` can perform that call internally.

Answer (score 0):

Just one additional option (the other answers are fine too):

```
lst = ['ABCD', 'EFGH', 'IJKL']

''.join(map(''.join, zip(*lst)))
```

For the given input, [hemflit's `chain.from_iterable` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42754477/364696) is faster, but for a larger number of input strings (even increasing from 3 to 6), this approach wins.

Also, as a side-note, you can also handle inputs with mismatched `len` without dropping data using `itertools.zip_longest`, passing `fillvalue=''`.